# EPPlus few chart in loop

Tags: asp.net, charts, epplus

How add a few chart in loop .
I try this but I have only one:

```
 for (int x = 1; x < 5; x++)
                {
 var chart = worksheet.Drawings.AddChart(zaklad, OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.Chart.eChartType.ColumnClustered);
                    chart.Title.Text = "Total";
                    chart.SetPosition(wiersz, 14, wiersz * x, 25);
                    chart.SetSize(100, 100*x);
                    worksheet.Cells[wiersz, 14, wiersz + 1, 25].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                    ExcelAddress valueAddress = new ExcelAddress(wiersz, 14 , wiersz + 1, 25);
                    chart.Legend.Border.LineStyle = eLineStyle.Solid;
                    chart.Legend.Border.Fill.Style = eFillStyle.SolidFill;
                    chart.Legend.Border.Fill.Color = Color.DarkBlue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're drawing the last one (and the biggest according to your code) above the others.
Try the following:

```
// left, top, width, height
chart.SetPosition(0, 0, 100 * x, 100);
chart.SetSize(100, 100);
```

Comment: I looking   like this:                                                                                                                   ArrayList wykres = new ArrayList();
                 wykres.Add(worksheet.Drawings.AddChart(zaklad, OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.Chart.eChartType.ColumnClustered));